# Unit test passes when in debug but fails when run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, testing

A search method returns any matching Articles and the most recent Non-matching articles up to a specified number.

Prior to being returned, the IsMatch property of the matching articles is set to true as follows:

articles = matchingArticles.Select(c => { c.IsMatch = true; return c; }).ToList();

In a test of this method,

```
    [Test]
    public void SearchForArticle1Returns1MatchingArticleFirstInTheList()
    {
        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var maxResults = 10;
            var searchPhrase = "Article1";
            IArticleRepository articleRepository = new ArticleRepository(session);
            var articles = articleRepository.GetSearchResultSet(searchPhrase, maxResults);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, articles.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, articles.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(searchPhrase)).Count());
            var article = articles[0];
            Assert.IsTrue(article.Title.Contains(searchPhrase));
            Assert.IsTrue(article.IsMatch);
        }
    }
```

All assertions pass when the test is run in debug, however the final assertion fails when the test is run in release:

Expected: True
  But was:  False

In the app itself the response is correct.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Edit:

I figured out what the problem is. It's essentially a race condition. When I am setting up the tests, I am dropping the db table, recreating it and populating it with the test data. Since the search relies on Full Text search, I am creating a text index on the relevant columns and setting it to auto populate. When this is run in debug, there appears to be sufficient time to populate the text index and the search query returns matches. When I run the test I don't think the index has been populated in time, no matches are returned and the test fails. It's similar to issues with datetimes. If I put a delay between creating the catalog and running the test the test passes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the checks for count==10 and count==1, and then you arbitrarily pick articles[0]. How much control is there over the order of articles?

Comment: Like @Henk Holterman said you should probably filter the to where it contains searchPhrase and then get the first one

Comment: @Henk Holterman, @Oskar Kjellin Thanks for looking.

The matching Article is first in the list, that's taken care of in the repository method and tested elsewhere.  However, If I do as you suggest:
`//var article = articles[0];
                var article = articles.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(searchPhrase)).ToList()[0];
                Assert.IsTrue(article.Title.Contains(searchPhrase));
                Assert.IsTrue(article.IsMatch);`

The result is the same.

Comment: @Pones When you say `when the test is run in release` - did you mean that or just when not Debugging the test?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin, the final assertion: Assert.IsTrue(article.IsMatch);

@wal, I mean when not debugging the test - just running with re#er.

Comment: @Pones it is impossible to answer with the given code, we need more code from the rep

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin - updated with repo methods, as indicated matching articles have their IsMatch property set to true by:
matchingArticles.Select(c => { c.IsMatch = true; return c; }).ToList();

Answer (score 12):

Pones, you have since clarified that the unit test fails when not debugging.

At this stage it could be anything however you should continue to run the unit test not debugging and insert the following statement somewhere you know (or think you know) is true

```
 if(condition)
            Debugger.Launch();
```

This will do the obvious and allow you to zone in on whats going wrong. 1 Place i suggest is on the `IsMatch` property (for starters)

Another common place you can run into issues like this is using DateTime's. If your unit test is running 'too fast' then it may break an assumption you had.

Comment: When I run as suggested and examine the IsMatch property of the Article is false.  So the assertion is failing. If I repeat in debug the IsMatch property is true.

Comment: did you try Debugger.Launch( ) when not running under Debug?

Comment: Yes.  When I did I could examine the IsMatch property and it was false.

Comment: ok, what about after this line?
`return matchingArticles.Select(c => { c.IsMatch = true; return c; }).ToList();;`

(extract the return value to a variable before returning so you can inspect)

Comment: var articles = matchingArticles.Select(c => { c.IsMatch = true; return c; }).ToList();
                return articles;
If i launch the debugger before this line is executed, then inspect the articles they all have a IsMatch==true property and ultimately the test passes.  If I launch the debuggerafter this is executed and inspect the returned articles the IsMatch property is false.

Comment: ok so you have narrowed it down somewhat. you now need to drill further. perhaps expand out the statement some more or re-write it not using a `Select` statement. how about the `IsMatch` setter? I am only guessing - you now have something to go with as you know that articles list should not contain any IsMatch=false when you just assigned them to true.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is.  It's essentially a race condition.  When I am setting up the tests, I am dropping the db table, recreating it and populating it with the test data. Since the search relies on Full Text search, I am creating a text index on the relevant columns and setting it to auto populate.  When this is run in debug, there appears to be sufficient time to populate the text index and the search query returns matches.  When I run the test I don't think the index has been populated in time, no matches are returned and the test fails. It's simlar to issues with datetimes.

Comment: glad you found it. consider updating your original question with your findings and/or upvoting/accepting any comments or answers that helped you fix your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously the problem will be different for other users, but I just hit it, and figured my solution may help some.  Basically when you are running in debug mode, you are running a single test only.  When you are running in run mode, you are running multiple tests in addition to the one you are having a problem with.

In my situation the problem was those other tests writing to a global list that I was not explicitly clearing in my test setup.  I fixed the issue by clearing the list at the beginning of the test.

My advice to see if this is the type of problem you are facing would be to disable all other tests and only 'run' the test you have an issue with.  If it works when ran by itself, but not with others, you'll know you have some dependency between tests.

Another tip is to use `Console.WriteLine("test")` statements in the test.  That's actually how I found my list had items with it leftover from another test.

Comment: This! There are several questions of "run fails debug pass" at SO. It doesn't matter, what the precise test code is. The problem is, that running a test suite executes much more code, than debugging one. Check for test interference!

Answer (score 0):

try to `print out` the actual result that you are comparing them with expected on `debug` and `normal run`

in my case, `I created entities` (JBA) `in the test method`

in `debug` mode, the `generated ids` were 1, 2 and 3

but in the `normal running` mode, they ware `different`

that caused my `hard-coded` values to make the test fail, so I changed them to get id from entity instead of the hard-coded way

hope this helps